# How do I generate the HTML element for every value of the array with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my HTML element :

```
        <li class="comment author-comment">

                <div class="info">
                    <a href="#">Jack Smith</a>
                    <span>3 hours ago</span>
                </div>

                <a class="avatar" href="#">
                    <img src="{{ 
            asset('commentui/images/avatar_author.jpg') }}" width="35" 
             alt="Profile Avatar" title="Jack Smith" />
                </a>

                <p>Value is here</p>

      </li>
```

Here is my JQuery code :

```
   $.get('{{ URL::to('comment/retrive') }}',function(data){
    console.log(data);
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
      $('.comment p').html(value.comment);
    });
   });
```

I need to generate The HTML Element with every value of the data or value.comment. So that it creates a list of the values, But now I am getting only the first one value.
Please help.

The data is retriving an object as the image here and I need to print the comment only in list :
[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to use another selector within your `each` function? It will overwrite all previous inputs in each loop

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
$('.comment p').html(value.comment);
```

By

```
$('.comment p').append(value.comment);
```

Because with *.html* each loop will override the previous one.

But *Append* will add your value after the previous.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new element for each line, not just update your single element text value :

```
var rp=$('.comment p');
$.each(data, function(key, value){
  var p = $('<p>');
  rp.append(p);
  p.text(value.comment);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try appending the data instead of replacing it.